# Custom admin page too many redirects Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, redirect, nginx

I'm starting to get familiar with Magento 2.

I installed v2.3.1 in an Nginx/PHP-fpm and got it working, including the sample data.

Then I followed everything in the tutorial at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/example-module-adminpage.html

The menu shows up ok, but when I click the link generated in the menu:

```
adminlink/exampleadminnewpage/helloworld/index/key/(removed-key)/
```

I get the Too many redirects and tries to redirect to:

> adminlink/exampleadminnewpage/helloworld/index/key/(removed-key)/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/dashboard

All other pages, frontend and backend, work fine.

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to debug this error and found that the the rewrite/redirect is not from Nginx it self.

In `app/code/Magento/Backend/App/Request/BackendValidator.php`, function `validate` (called from `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php`) when I try to access the new module the `$action` is instance of `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor`, which fails the test for not being instance of `AbstractAction` and start the redirect. But other pages (for example trying to access Content -> Pages) are instance of `Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Page\Index\Interceptor` that pass that test.

**EDIT 2:**

In `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php` function `processRequest` the `$this->requestValidator->validate($request, $actionInstance)` throws an Exception "Invalid request received" for my custom module. And Null in other pages from Magento.

In `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/Base.php` function `matchAction` $modules finds the correct module `MyCompany_ExampleAdminNewPage` and the cms page finds the `Magento_Cms`.

Then i found that in the same `matchAction`, magento didn't retrieve any actionList for the custom module. Which led me to conclude something should be wrong wih my `app/code/MyCompany/ExampleAdminNewPage/Controller/Adminhtml/HelloWorld/Index.php`. So i deleted and created a new one, checked for correct file permissions and ownership, and it solved my problem. Could also be the file encoding messing something up (wouldn't be the first, and won't be the last time this will happen).

Comment: Please place your all files code here so we can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the code here. Please check and compare with your code. And do correction if need.

> \app\code\MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage\registration.php

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'MyCompany_ExampleAdminNewPage',
        __DIR__
    );
```

> \app\code\MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
      <module name="MyCompany_ExampleAdminNewPage" setup_version="1.0.0">
      </module>
    </config>
```

> \app\code\MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
        <menu>
          <add id="MyCompany_ExampleAdminNewPage::greetings" title="Greetings" translate="title" module="MyCompany_ExampleAdminNewPage" parent="Magento_Backend::content" sortOrder="50" dependsOnModule="MyCompany_ExampleAdminNewPage" resource="MyCompany_ExampleAdminNewPage::greetings"/>
          <add id="MyCompany_ExampleAdminNewPage::greetings_helloworld" title="Hello World" translate="title" module="MyCompany_ExampleAdminNewPage" parent="MyCompany_ExampleAdminNewPage::greetings" sortOrder="10" dependsOnModule="MyCompany_ExampleAdminNewPage" action="exampleadminnewpage/helloworld" resource="MyCompany_ExampleAdminNewPage::greetings"/>
        </menu>
    </config>
```

> \app\code\MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
      <router id="admin">
          <route id="exampleadminnewpage" frontName="exampleadminnewpage">
              <module name="MyCompany_ExampleAdminNewPage"/>
          </route>
      </router>
  </config>
```

> \app\code\MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage\Controller\Adminhtml\HelloWorld\Index.php

```
<?php
      namespace MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage\Controller\Adminhtml\HelloWorld;

      class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
      {
        /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
        */
        protected $resultPageFactory;

        /**
         * Constructor
         *
         * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        ) {
             parent::__construct($context);
             $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        }

        /**
         * Load the page defined in view/adminhtml/layout/exampleadminnewpage_helloworld_index.xml
         *
         * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
         */
        public function execute()
        {
             return  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        }
      }
    ?>
```

> \app\code\MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage\view\adminhtml\layout\exampleadminnewpage_helloworld_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <title>
                Greetings
            </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="MyCompany_ExampleAdminNewPage::helloworld.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

> \app\code\MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage\view\adminhtml\templates\helloworld.phtml

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Use above code I have installed and It's working fine.

Comment: It's exactly the same that i have. Are you running on nginx or apache? I'm running on nginx.

Comment: I m on apache..

Comment: marked as the correct answer, even not knowing what was cleary wrong in my file, these are the correct steps to create a new admin module. something was wrong with my file, i'm betting on the permissions or encoding.

Comment: ☺ after all is it working now? And thanks for mark as right.

Comment: yes, it's working. i'll keep trying to learn the next steps for module development. thank you.